# Twitter Widget Height Problem

Tags: javascript, css, twitter

I'm working on a new website that uses twitter's embeddable widget (see http://twitter.com/goodies/widgets ).

You can control the widget's dimensions - width can be a fixed number of pixels or be set to 'auto'. Unfortunately I'm unable to convince the widget's height to be set to 'auto', which causes problems on long pages as large areas of white space appear under the fixed-height widget.

Has anyone experienced the same problem / found a resolution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can you be sure that the page length won't change after you create the widget?

Answer (score 0):

I use this: (which I found elsewhere on the web, though have tested it in Safari (5.0.3), Chrome (9.0.597), and Firefox (3.6.12) (all MacOSX)):

```
height: 'auto; -arnom-nl: 0'
```

Caveat: In some cases you may find the widget sometimes extends further than other content on the page.